# Python Twisted continuous reconnect attempts

Tags: python-3.x, twisted

When trying to connect a factory I want it to periodically try to reconnect if it fails to do so. I tried it with a code looking like that:

```
def reconnect():
    print("this sucks")
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 6667, factory2)

factory2 = pb.PBClientFactory()
factory2.clientConnectionFailed(reconnect(), "reasons")
reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 6667, factory2)
```

If I run this code it prints "this sucks" just once, although calling the connectTCP method with factory2 as parameter again. How should I go about implementing the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clientConnectionFailed` is a method that is called *by Twisted* on a factory *when a connection attempt fails*.  The usage in your example is nonsensical.

See `ReconnectingClientFactory` for one solution:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ReconnectingClientFactory
from twisted.internet import reactor

from yourlib import YourProtocol

factory = ReconnectingClientFactory()
factory.protocol = YourProtocol

reactor.connectTCP(host, port, factory)
reactor.run()
```

However, this does not combine well with PB due to the use of a custom factory class to support PB.  This is just one of many reasons to avoid using PB at all.

A more recently introduced solution is `ClientService`:

```
from twisted.application.internet import ClientService
from twisted.internet.endpoints import HostnameEndpoint

from yourlib import YourFactory

factory = YourFactory()

service = ClientService(
    HostnameEndpoint(reactor, host, port),
    YourFactory(),
)
service.startService()
reactor.run()
```

Note I've skipped over correct "service" usage here for brevity; see the Twisted 
service documentation for details on correct usage.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this was exactly what I was looking for.